# Bootstrap collapse resize table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8"> 
            <h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseList" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseList"> 1 Lecturer List</h3>
            <table class="table table-bordered collapse" id="collapseList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>List Id</th>
                    <th>List Name</th>
                    <th>Total Subscribers</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>Problems</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>abcdefg</td>
                <td>a</td>
                <td>Synchronize</td>
                <td>NOK</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I have when I click on the header label, it appears 1 second :

[image]

And after 1 second, this is what I have :

[image]

Why does my table is resized after the collapsing ? Is there a way to not resize the table ?

UPDATE :

Here's a JSfiddle, you can try and see yourself that there's a problem https://jsfiddle.net/0zw5a845/

Comment: do you have any js code on collapsing?

Comment: No, I have no javascript on this page

Comment: Please provide to us an MVCE example for us, but my guess is that your diving is uncollapsing due the fact that you have a col-md-8 instead of col-md-12.

Comment: I tried with col-md-12 and the same problem appears, except that the table is bigger at the end
What I did was already a MVCE no ? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS line to your main style sheet. This essentially overwrites the `.collapse.in` selector of the bootstrap style sheet.

```
.collapse.in {display:table}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zw5a845/1/)

Comment: Browsers naturally render `<table>` elements with the `display:table` property, but since you explicitly set the table to be a block-level element, the `cell-padding`, `cell-spacing`, and overall rules dictating how a table should be rendered are inherently altered.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly due to the fact that your div has a class of `col-md-8`.

If you want a table spanning the full width of a page, change the class to `col-md-12`.

Comment: this what what I had at first, but same problem, except that the table is bigger during the second of animation during the collapsing